# Cannot get current item from custom GetAllowedRenderings pipelines processor

Tags: pipelines, sitecore-api

I am writing a custom `GetAllowedRenderings` processor, but I cannot see how to obtain the current item that I'm editing in the experience editor.

There doesn't seem to be a property on the `GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs` args and `Sitecore.Context.Item` is `null`.

How can I get the current item in this context?

Comment: It is expected. Getting allowed renderings is executed for placeholder, not for item. That is why there is no context item. Why do you need context item? Do you want to show different allowed controls depending on page in Experience Editor mode?

Comment: Yes - we have a generic grid layout, but I only want to allow certain controls if the page is of a certain template..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I did a combination of Anton's suggestion as well as extending the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering` command.

It turns out that the `getPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline is invoked from the GetPlaceholderChromeData processor (as Anton suggested) *and* the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering` command. Without passing in the context item from the latter it would be be null when clicking the 'Add here' button in the experience editor.

Unfortunately the `AddRendering` command is difficult to extend because it's methods are all `protected/private static`, so I had to de-compile it and paste the code into a new version adding the following line to the `RunGetPlaceholderRenderingsPipeline` method:

`placeholderRenderingsArgs.CustomData["CurrentItem"] = Client.GetItemNotNull(context["contextitempath"]);`

Then I just needed to add the new command via a config patch:

```
<commands>
  <command name="webedit:addrendering" type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor">
    <patch:attribute name="type">Foundation.RestrictedRenderings.Infrastructure.Commands.AddRendering, Foundation.RestrictedRenderings</patch:attribute>
  </command>
</commands>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will require customization of Sitecore pipelines:

1. Override `Sitecore.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetPlaceholderChromeData` processor in `getChromeData` pipeline. It should call `getPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline with transferring Context page in `PlaceholderRenderingsArgs`. Use `CustomData` property or create your own pipeline arguments class.
2. Access from your custom `GetAllowedRenderings` processor to `CustomData` property with Context and use it.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit awkward because I already have a DynamicPlaceholder implementation overriding this, but it makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this and initially it appeared to work, but it seems that the `GetPlaceholderChromeData` is only called on page load, and it isn't called when clicking on the "Add here" button on a placeholder. Which means my customData is not set when the `GetAllowedRenderings` processor fires. Is the `getPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline called from elsewhere?